# Monitor queue - ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-structures, collections, monitor

I want to implement a monitor queue that two unrelated threads can share addition to it. Is it enough to use just `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` in this case or should I do it differently? I want to implement Active Object Design Pattern and there is ActivationQueue - it is ordinary Java queue that must be implemented as a monitor object, because addition to queue by other components of pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a thread-safe `Queue`, a [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) could be enough for you but if you rather need a thread-safe `BlockingQueue`, you should use a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) instead for such need like the example of implementation of the pattern Active Object on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object#Java).

```
class OriginalClass {

    private double val = 0.0;

    void doSomething() {
        val = 1.0;
    }

    void doSomethingElse() {
        val = 2.0;
    }
}

class BecomeActiveObject {

    private double val = 0.0;

    private BlockingQueue<Runnable> dispatchQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();

    public BecomeActiveObject() {
        new Thread (new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(true) {
                        try {
                            dispatchQueue.take().run();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {   
                            // okay, just terminate the dispatcher
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ).start();
    }

    //
    void doSomething() throws InterruptedException {
        dispatchQueue.put(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() { 
                    val = 1.0; 
                }
            }
        );
    }

    //
    void doSomethingElse() throws InterruptedException {
        dispatchQueue.put(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() { 
                    val = 2.0; 
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```